# Same gauge steps, with different implementation

Tags: gauge, getgauge

I am working on my project and I have one problem I need to solve.
I have one repo with specs in Gauge framework, but specs are for 3 almost identical sites.
I mean functionality is identical but locators, number of inputs and so on is not.
Is there any way how to have more step implementations for same step ?

Example:

- site1
- site2
- site3

Each site has own folder in root, where I have specs and concepts.
In src folder I have implementation of steps.

I need to have step like: `* Fill contact page with info` for each site, but each site have different locators, or some more inputs.

Any idea how to deal with that so I won't have duplicates ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you seen [Step Alias](https://docs.gauge.org/writing-specifications.html#step-alias)? Looks like that might help

Comment: Thanks, Yes I saw that but I need exact opposite.
I need to have one step that will have two different concepts, depending on folder or spec name.

Answer (score 1):

you can implement the same step in three different directories for the different sites. and set env variable `STEP_IMPL_DIR` to your directory where you're working currently.

example: -

you have three directories in the project root

- site1
- site2
- site3

set `STEP_IMPL_DIR = site3` for working with site3.

you can set multiple directories also. like -
`STEP_IMPL_DIR = common_tests_dir, site3`

Look about the config for language plugin in [docs](https://docs.gauge.org/configuration.html#language-plugin)

Comment: Thanks, thats almost what I was looking for.At first I need to use different concept files for same step not implementations. Second, I am not sure how it will work when I run them all I can not dynamically change that value I guess. But thanks I will think about that and maybe I can come up with something.

I was thinking about something similar but with excluding other folders.